# How to define a label dynamically in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, label

I have a Userform with a listview. In this listview one column is defined with checkboxes. So, when users click on checkboxes in several rows then I want to display the selected IDs in a caption of a label, e.g.:
`"You are selected: 848, 12133, 414"`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just saw that you are talking about a listview...

Here is a modified code snippet from AlphaFrog on [ExcelForum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1109477-how-to-retain-listview-checkboxes-state-before-unload-userform.html):

```
Private Sub Listview1_ItemCheck(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)

Dim si As MSComctlLib.ListSubItem

    For Each si In Item.ListSubItems
        si.ForeColor = IIf(Item.Checked, vbBlue, vbBlack)
    Next

End Sub
```

What he does is change the Fontcolour depending on the status of the Checkboxes (`Item.Checked`).

You can use the logic of my original reply below to get your desired results.

---

**Original reply:**

Here is an example with 3 checkboxes, I'll only be posting the code for Checkbox1 as well as the initialisation. The code in Checkbox1_Click goes one-to-one into Checkbox2_Click and Checkbox3_Click.

```
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim checked() As Integer
Dim tmp As Integer

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    cnt = 0

    ReDim checked(1 To 3)

    tmp = 1

    For i = 1 To 3
        If UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value = True Then
            checked(tmp) = i
            cnt = cnt + 1
            tmp = tmp + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Select Case cnt

        Case 0
        Label1.Caption = ""

        Case 1
        Label1.Caption = "You have selected: " & UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & checked(tmp - 1)).Caption

        Case Is > 1
        Label1.Caption = "You have selected: " & UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & checked(1)).Caption
        For t = 2 To tmp - 1
            Label1.Caption = Label1.Caption & ", " & UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & checked(t)).Caption
        Next t

    End Select

End Sub

'same code here for Checkbox2 and 3


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    For i = 1 To 3
        UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = False
    Next i

    Label1.Caption = ""

End Sub
```

Proof of concept:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! It was helpful :)

Comment: @yuro Glad it helped :D